# Cyber crime - data set

Tags: nlp, data-mining, web-scraping

I'm doing science project on my university to make an app, which uses AI to detect cyber crimes. I'm looking for sites to make my data set. Do you know any with ads like tobacco, alcohol, prescriptions, drugs, forgery? I'm using LASER embedder, so the site can be in almost any language. I'm looking for something like *OLX*, which allows illegal content. Dark web is fine as well.

I'm aware this question can somehow violate *stackexchange* terms of use. Please don't post particular site with an add, just a domain. I'll find posts myself. Something like *avito.ru* will do.

Comment: Maybe https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ would be a better forum for this question. Maybe even https://security.stackexchange.com, but I don't know if it would be on-topic.